# Getting images from a 3D numpy array of images using an array of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, matplotlib

I have 500 10x10 images in a numpy array of shape (10,10,500) and I want to take out images from some indexes which I have saved in a numpy array.
For example `indexes = array([201, 203, 208])` out of the 500.

`images.shape # (10,10,500)`

I found out that I can do `images[...,200]` to get the 200th image, but can I do that automatically for the whole array of indexes or do i need to have a for loop over indexes and append them one by one to a new array?

Comment: while you are free to use any arrangement of axis you see fit, BUT using the first index (from the left) for the "image number" can potentially speed up you code because each image will be in a continuous part of the memory, while in your case, each pixel is stored next to a pixel from another image, and the memory will be very fragmented, ie: numpy has to scan all the images just to grab 1 image.

Comment: as for your answer it's simply `images[:, :, indexes]`, pretty sure this question was asked a million times and you haven't searched for it.

Comment: thank you that works and I have searched for it probably not long enough as it seems